# What is 0x10 in decimal?

Tags: c#, numbers, hex

I have the following code:

```
SN.get_Chars(5)
```

`SN` is a string so this should give the 5th Char. Ok!

Now I have another code but: `SN.get_Chars(0x10)`

I wonder what 0x10 is? Is it a number? If it's so, then what is it in decimal notation?

Comment: In google, type "0x10 in decimal".  Google calculator will convert them for you

Comment: You can also use the "Any Base Calculator" on the Android market to do this: http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ewe.radixcalculator

Comment: You can also use windows calculator in programmer mode!

Comment: Uh............. 16?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

0x means the number is [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), or base 16.

0x10 is 16.

Answer (score 93):

`0xNNNN` (not necessarily four digits) represents, in C at least, a hexadecimal (base-16 because 'hex' is 6 and 'dec' is 10 in Latin-derived languages) number, where `N` is one of the digits `0` through `9` or `A` through `F` (or their lower case equivalents, either representing 10 through 15), and there may be 1 or more of those digits in the number. The other way of representing it is NNNN<sub>16</sub>.

It's very useful in the computer world as a single hex digit represents four bits (binary digits). That's because four bits, each with two possible values, gives you a total of `2 x 2 x 2 x 2` or `16` (2<sup>4</sup>) values. In other words:

```
  _____________________________________bits____________________________________
 /                                                                             \
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| bF | bE | bD | bC | bB | bA | b9 | b8 | b7 | b6 | b5 | b4 | b3 | b2 | b1 | b0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
 \_________________/ \_________________/ \_________________/ \_________________/ 
      Hex digit           Hex digit           Hex digit           Hex digit
```

A base-X number is a number where each position represents a multiple of a power of X.

---

In base 10, which we humans are used to, the digits used are `0` through `9`, and the number 7304<sub>10</sub> is:

- (7 x 10<sup>3</sup>) = 7000<sub>10</sub> ; plus
- (3 x 10<sup>2</sup>) = 300<sub>10</sub> ; plus
- (0 x 10<sup>1</sup>) = 0<sub>10</sub> ; plus
- (4 x 10<sup>0</sup>) = 4<sub>10</sub> ; equals 7304.

---

In octal, where the digits are `0` through `7`. the number 754<sub>8</sub> is:

- (7 x 8<sup>2</sup>) = 448<sub>10</sub> ; plus
- (5 x 8<sup>1</sup>) = 40<sub>10</sub> ; plus
- (4 x 8<sup>0</sup>) = 4<sub>10</sub> ; equals 492<sub>10</sub>.

Octal numbers in C are preceded by the character `0` so `0123` is not 123 but is instead (1 * 64) + (2 * 8) + 3, or 83.

---

In binary, where the digits are `0` and `1`. the number 1011<sub>2</sub> is:

- (1 x 2<sup>3</sup>) = 8<sub>10</sub> ; plus
- (0 x 2<sup>2</sup>) = 0<sub>10</sub> ; plus
- (1 x 2<sup>1</sup>) = 2<sub>10</sub> ; plus
- (1 x 2<sup>0</sup>) = 1<sub>10</sub> ; equals 11<sub>10</sub>.

---

In hexadecimal, where the digits are `0` through `9` and `A` through `F` (which represent the "digits" `10` through `15`). the number 7F24<sub>16</sub> is:

- (7 x 16<sup>3</sup>) = 28672<sub>10</sub> ; plus
- (F x 16<sup>2</sup>) = 3840<sub>10</sub> ; plus
- (2 x 16<sup>1</sup>) = 32<sub>10</sub> ; plus
- (4 x 16<sup>0</sup>) = 4<sub>10</sub> ; equals 32548<sub>10</sub>.

Your relatively simple number `0x10`, which is the way C represents 10<sub>16</sub>, is simply:

- (1 x 16<sup>1</sup>) = 16<sub>10</sub> ; plus
- (0 x 16<sup>0</sup>) = 0<sub>10</sub> ; equals 16<sub>10</sub>.

As an aside, the different bases of numbers are used for many things.

- base 10 is used, as previously mentioned, by we humans with 10 digits on our hands.
- base 2 is used by computers due to the relative ease of representing the two binary states with electrical circuits.
- base 8 is used almost exclusively in UNIX file permissions so that each octal digit represents a 3-tuple of binary permissions (read/write/execute). It's also used in C-based languages and UNIX utilities to inject binary characters into an otherwise printable-character-only data stream.
- base 16 is a convenient way to represent four bits to a digit, especially as most architectures nowadays have a word size which is a multiple of four bits.
- base 64 is used in encoding mail so that binary files may be sent using only printable characters. Each digit represents six binary digits so you can pack three eight-bit characters into four six-bit digits (25% increased file size but guaranteed to get through the mail gateways untouched).
- as a semi-useful snippet, base 60 comes from some very old civilisation (Babylon, Sumeria, Mesopotamia or something like that) and is the source of 60 seconds/minutes in the minute/hour, 360 degrees in a circle, 60 minutes (of arc) in a degree and so on [not really related to the computer industry, but interesting nonetheless].
- as an even less-useful snippet, the ultimate question and answer in [The Hitchhikers Guide To The Galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) was "What do you get when you multiply 6 by 9?" and "42". Whilst same say this is because the Earth computer was faulty, others see it as proof that the creator has 13 fingers :-)

Comment: +1 for thoroughness and a math lesson, but don't forget poor old base-2 ;-)

Comment: I don't like to speak authoritatively on things I know little about. It may have been the Babylonians, Sumerians or Mesopotamians - you may just as well say the Iraqis for all I'd know. I'll leave that to the history buffs (my interest in ancient history is adequate but not comprehensive).

Comment: Iraq doesn't exactly fall under "ancient history", as it was founded in the 20th century :-)

Comment: @EddieD, I meant it's all in the same area. I think. My geography is far worse than my history :-)

Comment: I think it was in Voodoo Child that a 6 turned out to be 9.

Comment: @Louis: old I am, young padawan, but 5000 years old not am I :-) Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal - they seem to think it was because 60 has bucketloads of factors.

Comment: we should create or add this to wiki, very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The simple version is 0x is a prefix denoting a hexadecimal number, [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

So the value you're computing is *after* the prefix, in this case 10.

But that is not the number 10.  The most significant bit `1` denotes the hex value while `0` denotes the units.

So the simple math you would do is

**0x10**

```
1 * 16 + 0 = 16
```

Note - you use 16 because hex is base 16.

Another example:

**0xF7**

```
15 * 16 + 7 = 247
```

You can get a list of values by searching for a hex table.  For instance in this [chart](https://www.google.com/search?q=hex+table&rlz=1C1GKLB_enUS640US640&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOpMOr_fzTAhUHw2MKHbjUAtoQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=950#imgrc=2U31hF4tTw886M:) notice F corresponds with 15.

Answer (score 3):

It's a hex number and is 16 decimal.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that '10' is the representation of the base in that base:

10 is 2(decimal) in base-2

10 is 3(decimal) in base-3

...

10 is 10(decimal) in base-10

...

10 is 16(decimal) in base-16 (hexadecimal)

...

10 is 1024(decimal) in base-1024

...and so on