# What is the difference between “18” and “0x18”?

Tags: c#, integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is 0x10 in decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692286/what-is-0x10-in-decimal)

I notice that

```
Console.WriteLine(18);
```

writes 18, but

```
Console.WriteLine(0x18);
```

writes 24. What does this mean?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `0x` prefix indicates that the following number is in [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) format. i.e. the base 16 number system. So the number `0x18` is (in base 10) (1 * 16^1) + (8 * 16^0) = 24 (remember: 16^0 = 1).

Your example without the prefix `18` is in base 10 already as you would probably expect.