# VB6 RS232 commands not working

Tags: vb6, serial-port

I have the following code:

```
MSCommProj.CommPort = 6
MSCommProj.RThreshold = 1
MSCommProj.Settings = "19200,N,8,1"
MSCommProj.InputLen = 0
MSCommProj.PortOpen = True
```

And it opens just fine and connects but when i try sending the command:

```
MSCommProj.Output = "21 8901 5057 31 0A" & Chr$(13)
```

and

```
MSCommProj.Output = "21 89 01 50 57 31 0A" & Chr$(13)
```

and

```
MSCommProj.Output = "3F 89 01 50 57 0A" & Chr$(13)
```

as instructed by the user manual, it does not come on.

Here is the pages in the manual that shows this. Maybe i am just doing it wrong?:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You should send (and receive) in binary mode, as @gserg and @paxdiablo suggest. Before that, however, note that Page 69 says that you need a 19200bps connection; but, you're setting your serial port at 9600bps.

Comment: You risk unexpected errors fumbling around trying to shove byte values into strings as people keep suggesting.  Use a Byte array and do it right.  That way you won't trip over the implicit conversion to ANSI that can scramble your data.

Comment: @Bob: have an example of this by any chance? :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because i did not use a cross-over cable... All the rs232 codes were correct. Blah.

Answer (score 5):

Are you *sure* that you're meant to be sending *character* data to the RS232 interface for that? Those look like binary sequences to me.

Rather than:

```
MSCommProj.Output = "3F 89 01 50 57 0A" & Chr$(13)
```

I'd be looking at transmitting the binary data thus:

```
MSCommProj.Output = chr$(63) & chr$(137) & chr$(1) & chr$(80) & chr$(87) & chr(10)
```

You'll note that there's no `chr$(13)` at the end, the spec doesn't call for that.

---

If you want to know what the conversions are for those hex values, start up the Windows calculator, change the view to scientific, switch to hex mode, enter the value, the switch to decimal mode.

Or you can download an [ASCII table](http://bestofthisweb.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/ascii_table2.jpg) for this purpose. Or view one of my voluminous essays on the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692286/what-is-0x10-in-decimal/692310#692310).

Comment: is there an online converter for that? :o)

Comment: Cant seem to find the converting for 0A?

Comment: `0x0a` is `10` - I've added an addendum telling you how to figure them out, or you could get an ASCII table off the net which has both decimal and hex, for example: http://bestofthisweb.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/ascii_table2.jpg

Comment: @SteathRT, have a look at the uodate which provides a link on how to do this.

Comment: Well what i meant was to say that **chr$(63) & chr$(137) & chr$(1) & chr$(80) & chr$(87) & chr(10)** did not work either.

Comment: Well, then, there's a lot of _other_ things that could be wrong. If you're using `on error resume next`, Are you checking `err` to see if there's a problem in the setup? Do you actually have the device connected to the right port? Do you have a LED-style breakout box so you can see if the data and control lines are actually being toggled on the wire? Is the device correctly activating the control wires?I see that only rxd, txd and ground are connected but the Windows drivers might be relying on the fact that rts/cts handshaking is happening (which would prevent data from being sent).

Answer (score 2):

You are required to send bytes given.
You instead send string representation of those.

Send actual bytes.
`chr$(&h21) & chr$(&h89) & chr$(&h01) & chr$(&h50)` etc.

Comment: tried **MSCommProj.Output = Chr$(&H21) & Chr$(&H89) & Chr$(&H1) & Chr$(&H50) & Chr$(&H57) & Chr$(&H30) & Chr$(&HA)** but it did not do anything.